# MySQL Joining Two Tables Gives Incorrect Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join two queries to hopefully get the same results that I was receiving with individual queries. I am by no means skilled at MySQL join queries, thus my predicament. Here are my queries and their results.

**Here is query #1:**

```
select      sum(fbaoh.qty) as sumQty 
from        FBAOrderHistory fbaoh 
where       fbaoh.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6'
and         fbaoh.sku = '643356041428'
    and         fbaoh.account_id = 8
and         fbaoh.datetimePlaced BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11';
/*
sumQty = 139
*/
```

**Here is query #2:**

```
select      count(fbai.id) as totalRows
from        FBAInventory fbai 
LEFT JOIN       FBAInventoryReport fbair
ON          fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = fbair.id
where       fbai.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6'
and     fbai.sku = '643356041428'
    and         fbai.account_id = 8         
and         fbair.report_datetime BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11';
/*
totalRows = 30
*/
```

**Query #3 - Here are my queries joined together:**

```
select      sum(fbaoh.qty) as sumQty, 
            count(fbai.id) as totalRows
from        FBAOrderHistory fbaoh 
LEFT JOIN   FBAInventory fbai
 ON         fbaoh.asin=fbai.asin
LEFT JOIN   FBAInventoryReport fbair
 ON             fbai.FBAInventoryReport_id=fbair.id
where       fbaoh.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6'
and         fbaoh.sku = '643356041428'
    and         fbai.account_id = 8
and         fbaoh.account_id = 8        
and         fbaoh.datetimePlaced BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11'
and         fbair.report_datetime BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11';
/*
sumQty = 4170
totalRows = 3840
*/
```

Here are the table schemas:

**FBAOrderHistory**

```
 id | qty | sku     | asin    | datetimePlaced
 ------------------------------
 1  | 1   | ABC     | 123     | 2014-05-20 06:06:03
```

**FBAInventory**

```
 id | sku     | asin    | fbaInventoryReport_id
 ---------------------------------------------------
 1  | ABC     | 123     | 1
```

**FBAInventoryReport**

```
 id | report_datetime
 ---------------------------------------------------
 1  | 2014-05-20 06:06:03
```

Query #1 - I am getting the sum based upon the sku and the asin and the date range.

Query #2 - I am getting the total rows based upon the sku and the asin and the date range.

Query #3 - I am wanting to get the same results. The only connection between the two queries is the sku and the asin.

Obviously the results from the last query are not what I intended to receive. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I can tell. Instead of just showing me the sumQty and totalRows, the query is actually multiplying the sumQty (139) and the totalRows (30) together thus equaling: 4170. As for the 3840, I have no clue how this is being rendered.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide me!

Comment: Why do you want to join 2 totally different queries?

Comment: Can you post on your question your tables structure?

Comment: You're doing a "tree" join. `A->B` and `A->C`. If tables B and C have differening number of rows, you're going to get lopsided results. the "bigger" side will force the smaller side's missing rows to be filled in with nulls.

Comment: Queries are not self-explanatory. We have no idea what is in those three tables, or how they relate as a whole.

Comment: I am adding the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

These queries can't be joined because they will throw off the sum and count as you discovered.  The reason is that there isn't a one to one relationship between these tables.  The best way to do this is to join the results as follows:

```
select q1.sumQty, q2.totalRows
from(
select      sum(fbaoh.qty) as sumQty 
from        FBAOrderHistory fbaoh 
where       fbaoh.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6'
and         fbaoh.sku = '643356041428'
    and         fbaoh.account_id = 8
and         fbaoh.datetimePlaced BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11') q1,
(select      count(fbai.id) as totalRows
from        FBAInventory fbai 
LEFT JOIN       FBAInventoryReport fbair
ON          fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = fbair.id
where       fbai.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6'
and     fbai.sku = '643356041428'
    and         fbai.account_id = 8         
and         fbair.report_datetime BETWEEN '2014-05-12' AND '2014-06-11') q2
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the second query inherit the asin and sku from the first query. The reason that I am asking is because when I am all done with this query (many steps still to go) I will not be using a pre defined asin and sku such as this: "fbaoh.asin = 'B002BRSCJ6' and fbaoh.sku = '643356041428'". This query will just run over all rows and then render an array of results. Thanks!

Comment: @LargeTuna Not really.  In your php code it should be possible to pass the same value twice.  These really are two separate queries thanks to the aggregation so I don't know of a clean way to use the variable once.